# Active class Is not showing the declared css

Tags: php, css, html, menu

I'm echoing the "active" and "active-drop" classes when on the page. With the code below.

```
<?php if(is_page('page_name')){echo 'active';}?>">
<?php if(is_page('page_name')){echo 'active-drop';}?>">
<?php if(is_page (array ('ps3','xbox-360', 'switch', 'wiiu', '3ds', 'ps-vita', 'retro'), true)){echo 'active-drop';}?>
```

And the css for the classes are these:

```
.active {
  background: red;
}

.active-drop {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
 }

.arrow-left:before .active-drop { 
  border-right: 5px solid #fff; 
}
```

So far so good, the "active" class works as it should, but the "active-drop" class changes the background, but does not change the color and "arrow-left: before" does not change the color either. I think it's related to the color change in the hover, so I tried to be more specific about the active classes, even with the "+" selector, though it did not work. Using! Important worked for the "active-drop", but not for the "arrow-left: before". But I do not want to have to use !important. If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

```css
.header-menu {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul li {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-menu ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: block;   
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 180px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 70px;
}

.arrow-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 6px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

/*Dropdown 2*/

.arrow-left:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20.5px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
 
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 5px solid #000; 
}

.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario:hover:before {
  border-right: 5px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content-2:hover,
.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario:hover+.dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">PS4</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">XBOX ONE</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">PC</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">eSports</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="arrow-down active">Mais</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="drop-secundario active-drop arrow-left">Outros Consoles</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content-2">
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">PS3</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">XBOX 360</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">Switch</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">WII U</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">3DS</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">PS Vita</a>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">Retrô</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="active-drop">Contato</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.active-drop is under .dropdown-content so it is affected by ".header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a" style in css. The css below will override it.

```
.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a.active-drop {
 background-color: red;
 color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a.active-drop:before {
 border-right: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: As I said in the question "the "active" class works as it should", the problem is in the "active-drop" and in the "arrow-left: before"

Comment: it seems that .active-drop is under .dropdown-content so it is affected by .header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a style in css. I updated my answer, try if it works.